# Rendering several forms with helpers Crispy Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I'm having an issue using several forms with `django-crispy-forms` for Django.

From the documentation, we must set `self.helper.form_tag = False` in out Form. Documentation [here](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/crispy_tag_forms.html#rendering-several-forms-with-helpers)

Then wrapp the forms with a Form tag in the HTML.

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    X = forms.IntegerField(label='X', min_value=0, max_value=10)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            'X',
            Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='btn-success')
        )
class PredictForm(forms.Form):
    Y = forms.IntegerField(label='X', min_value=0, max_value=10)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            'Y',
            Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='btn-success')
        )
```

Then in the HTML file I have:

```
 <form action="my_action" class="uniForm" method="post">
    <div id="box" class="box">{% crispy formSearch formSearch.helper %}</div>
    <div id="box2" class="box2">{% crispy formPrediction formPrediction.helper %}</div>
 </form>
```

In my View.py:

```
def index(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    formSearch = SearchForm(request.POST)
    formPrediction = PredictionForm(request.POST)
    # Do stuff
  else
    formSearch = SearchForm()
    formSearch.fields['X'].initial = 5

    formPrediction = PredictionForm()
    formSearch.fields['Y'].initial = 5

return render(request, 'index.html', {'formSearch': formSearch}, 'formPrediction': formPrediction)
```

What I get is 2 crispy forms that are displayed on my web page, but the first forms tries to load the fields of the seconds forms. It seems like my second form is duplicated.

I get this error:

> KeyError: "Key 'Y' not found in 'SearchForm'. Choices are: X."

It is trying to get data from `PredictForm` but is aware that only `X` is in `SearchForm`. I thought it was I typo somewhere, but I can't find my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

A collision war made between the 2 forms, why? Because I did not initiate properly each form functions.

I have changed

```
self.helper = FormHelper
```

to

```
self.helper = FormHelper(self)
```